# How to sort array by array of order?

Tags: php

I have the following function that accepts array and order:

```
function toCSV($data, $order)
{

    $res = [];
    foreach ($data as $index =>  $row) {
        $str = [];
        foreach ($row as  $column) {
            foreach ($order as $key) {
                if ($column['key'] == $key)
                    $str[] =   $column;
            }
        }

        $res[$index] = $str;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

The `$data` is:

```
[[{"key":"num","value":"5132756002760855","indexrow":162,"columnindex":0}...]]
```

The `$order` is array of sequance:

```
$order = ['num', 'mm', 'yy', 'zip']
```

So, I try to sort first array by the second array. But it does not work for me. As result I get unsorted array.

Full `$data` array is:

```
[[{"key":"undetected","value":"","indexrow":25,"columnindex":0}],[{"key":"num","value":"5354562740628987","indexrow":64,"columnindex":0},{"key":"mmyy","value":"01\/26","indexrow":64,"columnindex":1}]]
```

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like sorting. Sorting means ordering an array from highest to lowest or vice versa.

Comment: I order by creating a new array and pushing element of array $array into

Comment: Can you show the desired result?

Comment: So you are only ordering the columns in each row but not the rows?

Comment: I try order columns in each rows

Comment: you don't have columns `mm`, `yy`, and `zip` in your data, what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if in the most inner loop will be true at some point and then the element is added, so the order doesn't change. Assuming you have only keys that appear in order. If you switch the two most inner loops it will work but it is not very efficient. O(nm) instead of O(n+m).

```
function toCSV($data, $order) {
    $res = [];
    foreach ($data as $index =>  $row) {
        $map = [];
        $str = [];
        foreach ($row as  $column) {
            if (array_key_exists($column['key'], $map))
                $map[$column['key']][] = $column;
            else
                $map[$column['key']] = [$column];
        }
        foreach ($order as $key) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $map))
                $str = array_merge($str, $map[$key]);
        }
        $res[$index] = $str;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

If a key can only exist once per row then you can simplify and don't have to use arrays in the map. Simplified version, also assuming each key in order appears once per column:

```
function toCSV($data, $order) {
    $res = [];
    foreach ($data as $index =>  $row) {
        $map = [];
        $str = [];
        foreach ($row as  $column)
            $map[$column['key']] = $column;
        foreach ($order as $key)
            $str[] = $map[$key];
            // to create key if it doesn't exist use the following:
            // $str[] = array_key_exists($key, $map) ? $map[$key] : [];
        $res[$index] = $str;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Both versions will discard columns with keys not in $order.

Comment: As result I git  empty: `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]` array

Comment: @Stasia I used row where I should have used column.

Comment: I did not get. I need to prepare this data to render in table on the client

Comment: May be create an row array. Then create empty arrays with keys as `["num" => [], "zip" => []]` Then fill these arrays by key?

Comment: @Stasia there was another mistake (loop closed at wrong place), also added simple version.

Comment: Could you edit the answer and fix it? I still can not get why I get res as empty array

Comment: @Stasia you tried the newest versions?

Comment: Yes, what is there is `$key` in `$map`? Error is: `Undefined array key "mm"`

Comment: @Stasia well then you have to use an array_key_exists, the simple version assumes all values in $order appear in each $row once per $column.

Comment: Could I use `if(isset($map[$key])) {}`

Comment: @Stasia yes that would work, btw. both versions will discard all columns that have a key which is not in $order.

Comment: if there is not $key in $map it must be created

Comment: @Stasia I also found out why you had empty array, I ignored the return value of array_merge

Comment: Could you modify answer and add this: `  if (isset($map[$key])) {
                    $str[] = $map[$key];
                } else {
                    $map[$key] = [];
                }`?

Comment: Problem is if there is not key in $data it must be created  in $res

Comment: @Stasia, see comment in code